# RX sub observable - execute only once

Tags: android, rx-java, observable

Normally I use

```
Observable observable = someObservable.replay().refCount();
```

to create an observable, that is executed only once. This works fine if I subscribe to `observable` multiple times like following:

```
observable.observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(...);

observable.observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(...);
```

The `observable` is only executed once - perfect, just as I want it. If I now do following:

```
Observable obs1 = observable.map(...); // call some operators
Observable obs2 = observable.map(...); // call some operators

obs1.observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(...);

obs2.observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(...);
```

Then the `observable` is executed twice. How can I make sure, that this won't happen?

Answer (score 10):

I think what you want is to add a `.take(1)` operator.  This way once something is read from the observable it will call onComplete.

Comment: I want to replay the whole sequence... I don't want to lose anything. All n items emitted by my observable should be emitted to any subscriber or in any chain, the observable is used in

Comment: ah I understand, you can use .cache() operator.  This way the first execution will create the observable while any other subscriber will get the exact same cached emissions.  Think of .cache as maintaining state for you.

Comment: this is working. I'm still confused, why the `refCount` is not working... Seems like `refCount` only works if I'm subscribing to the resulting observable directly (I've never read something about that yet though)... Using `autoConnect` instead works as well...